# ¿Cómo obtener un archivo csv a partir de dos arrays en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos array:

a = [codig_1,codigo_dos. código_3]

b = [[111111, 22222, 3333, 4444], [555555, 66666], [333,5555]]

quiero convertir esta informacióna un csv de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
exportToCsv = function() {
  var CsvString = "";
  b.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
    b.forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex) {
      CsvString += ColItem + ',';
    });
    CsvString += "\r\n";
  });
  CsvString = "data:application/csv," + encodeURIComponent(b);
```

pero en el resultado que obtengo siempre es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿En qué estaré fallando? gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 4):

Siempre es conveniente observar a lo que quieres llegar, en este caso a un csv con esta estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después, piensas el algoritmo, en este caso sería asociar cada elemento de la lista "a" con "b", independientemente de que cada elemento de "b" sea una lista.
Finalmente, solo debes jugar con las concatenaciones y dado que en la última posición no debes agregar una coma, le colocas un condicional para evitar ponerlo en el último elemento de "b" asociado a cada elemento de "a".

Este sería el código:

```
exportToCsv = function() {
    var CsvString = "";
    // Para cada elemento de "a"
    a.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
        // Inicias colocando el elemento a_i
        CsvString += RowItem + ","
        // Después asignas los elementos de b dejando el primer elemento vacio
        b[RowIndex].forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex){
            if(ColIndex == b[RowIndex].length - 1) 
                CsvString += ColItem + "\n" // En caso de ser el último elemento de b no se coloca coma 
            else
                CsvString += ColItem + "\n," 
        });
    });

    console.log(CsvString)
}
```

En caso de cargar el CSV en excel, este sería el resultado:

[image: CSV en excel]

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que tu segundo `forEach` repite el primero.

Con el primer `for` debes recorrer ambos array. Y con segundo `for` recorres el  array interno de `b`

Aquí un ejemplo, además incluyo una función para descargar el `CSV`

```
const a = ["codig_1","codigo_dos", "código_3"];
const b = [[111111, 22222, 3333, 4444], [555555, 66666], [333,5555]]

const exportToCsv = function(arr1,arr2){
    let filas=[];
    for(let i=0; i< arr1.length; i++){
      filas.push(`${arr1[i]},${arr2[i][0]}`);
      for(let j=1; j< arr2[i].length; j++){
         filas.push(`,${arr2[i][j]}`);
      }
    }
    const cvs = filas.join("\r\n");
    return "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(cvs);
}


function exportar(){
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("download", "nombrecsv.csv");
  link.href=exportToCsv(a,b);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.remove();
 
}
exportar();
```